# Error:(27, 17) error: element value must be a constant expression

Tags: android, module, annotations

I have a module that was application once but now i want to turn it into library module. But annotations are giving error like this:

Error:(27, 17) error: element value must be a constant expression

A sample class is like below:

```
@Animate(Animation.CARD_TOP_IN_DESC)
@NonReusable
@Layout(R.layout.gallery_item_small_list)
public class ContributorList {
```

Since injected views are created during runtime it gives the error above. 
So how can i handle the problem in a practical way(in my module there is more that 300 injected views)? I enabled "annotation processing" but no use.

If there is no way practically how can i write the class above in classical way?